# Are derived telemetries possible in Perfino, e.g. Heap % Used?

Tags: perfino

I'm currently evaluating Perfino 3.0. The sparklines on the VMs tab are great, but the JVMs I'm monitoring have widely differing max heap sizes. It would be more useful to have a Used Heap % telemetry shown.

I attempted to create a custom one by extracting MBean values for used heap (in bytes) and max heap (in bytes) but I don't see a way to divide one by the other to show a percentage. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to calculate something, you have to add a static method to your code and annotate it with [`@Telemetry`](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/perfino/help/api/doc/com/perfino/annotation/Telemetry.html). For example:

```
@Telemetry("Heap percentage", @TelemetryFormat(Unit.PERCENT))
```

However, your suggestion makes a lot of sense and we'll add a "Used Heap Percentage" VM telemetry in 3.0.1. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build of 3.0.1. It's already available on the [demo server](https://demo.ej-technologies.com).

Comment: That's fantastic! Any chance of a PermGen % somewhere down the line as well?

Comment: PermGen would only be interesting up to Java 7

Comment: Yeah. Sadly, stuck on 7 for a some legacy things -- moving off, slowly but surely. If you think it's of limited use, I totally get that -- good to know that a @Telemetry annotation can expose it, or whatever else we want. Thanks.